# What does "out"  mean before a Generic type parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-construction, c#-3.0

I've just saw an unfamiliar syntax while looking for `GroupBy` return type:

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>
```

[**MSDN Source**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx)

I know what does `out` mean in methods, but not in a generics interface.

What does `out` mean in a generic type?

Comment: It's a *Generic Modifier*. See MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is one of the two generic modifiers introduces in C# 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010).

It signifies that the generic parameter it is declared on is covariant.

The `in` modifier signifies the generic parameter it is declared on is contravariant.

See [out (Generic Modifier)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) and [in (Generic Modifier)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I know the terms [contravariance and covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), but the MSDN examples aren't describing the `in` and `out` modifiers for Generics very clear in my opinion. Can you give some examples which are easier to understand?

Comment: This is nothing but copy/paste from MSDN. Frank's answer should have been accepted, not this.

Comment: @SergeyAkopov - You are certainly entitled to your opinion, but accepting or not is entirely something that the question asker decides.

Answer (score 18):

It denotes a [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) parameter. See also the description on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). Essentially it says, that `IGrouping<Aderived, Bderived>` can be regarded as `IGrouping<Abase, Bbase>`, hence you can

```
IGrouping<Aderived, Bderived> gr = MakeGrouping(...);
IGrouping<Abase, Bbase> grBase = gr;
```

if `Aderived` is an interface or a type derived from `Abase`. This is a feature that comes in handy when you want to call a method that requires a parameter of type `IGrouping<Abase, Bbase>`, but you only got an object of type `IGrouping<Aderived, Bderived>`. In this case, both types can be considered equivalent due to the covariance of their type parameters.

Answer (score 4):

`out` keyword in this context would indicate the corresponding type parameter to be covariant simply speaking - covariance enables you to use a more derived type than that specified by the generic parameter.

BTW, see this ten part series from Eric Lippert to understand more about covariance and contra-variance: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: The link above is broken: Eric's article can now be found at: https://ericlippert.com/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-1/

Answer (score 4):

out just means that the type is only used for output e.g.

```
public interface Foo<out T>
{
   T Bar()
}
```

There also is a modifier in that means that the type is only used for input e.g.

```
public interface Foo<in T>
{
    int Bar(T x)
}
```

These are used because Interfaces with in are covariant in T and Interfaces with out are contravariant in T.

Comment: I assume you meant `public interface Foo<in T>` (instead of `out`) in your second example, am I right?

Comment: @ralzarek you have it backwards : out is covariant and in is contravariant