# What do the 'in' and '@' keywords do when defining interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Given the below interface declarations:

**Declaration A**

```
public interface EventHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T command);
}
```

**Declaration B**

```
public interface EventHandler<in T>
{
    void Handle(T @event);
}
```

In normal testing these all do the same thing. The `Handle` method is called as expected.

In what ways do the above vary, and how do they behave differently in other scenarios?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "out"  mean before a Generic type parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027611/what-does-out-mean-before-a-generic-type-parameter)

Comment: Regarding to `@`, it lets you use saved-keywords, as in the last example, `event` is a keyword and `var event = 2` won't compile, prefixing it with `@` will fix it.

Comment: Do the first two really work for you? I expected a compiler error for those, and I do get a compiler error for them.

Comment: @hvd, `int @event = 2;` should work just fine.

Comment: @gdoron I know, my question was to the OP, not to you. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: Apologies edited as blatant silly typo you pointed out @hvd. All comments and answer helped i had gotten confused with the dynamic @ combination

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`in` specifies a generic type parameter as a contravariant: [`in` (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx). There is also [`out` for covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

`@` allows you use registered keywords as identifiers:

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special
>   meanings to the compiler. **They cannot be used as identifiers in your
>   program unless they include `@` as a prefix**. For example, `@if` is a valid
>   identifier but `if` is not because if is a keyword.

*Source: [C# Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)*